# how to code the kernel mode of rt-linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, real-time

Interrupts are handled in the kernel mode but to handle interrupt in rt linux they are saying that :

I need to write code using RTLinux in kernel space and with kernel modules. With QNX, you can't write kernel modules (the kernel is not open) and you have real-time in user-space.

my question :
How to write a code in kernel space ??
what is exactly mean by that ??
where should i modify the kernel ??

someone Please suggest some ideas.

udp code :

```
 int CreateSocket()
 {
     socklen_t len;

   // Socket creation for UDP

   acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   if(acceptSocket==-1)

   {

     printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

     return 1;

   }

   else

   {

     printf("Socket started!\n");

   }

 memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

 addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

 addr.sin_port=htons(port);

 addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

 rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

 if(rc== -1)

 {

     printf("Oh dear, something went wrong with bind()! %s\n", strerror(errno));

   return 1;

 }

 else

 {

   printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
 }


   while(rc!=-1)
   {
     len = sizeof(client);
     rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);

     //I am calculating the time here
     InterruptTime = GetTimeStamp();
     measurements[17] = InterruptTime;

     if(rc==0)
     {
       printf("Server has no connection..\n");
       break;
     }
     if(rc==-1)
     {
         printf("Oh dear, something went wrong with read()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
       break;
     }

     XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );


   }

   close(acceptSocket);
   return 1;
   }

int main()
{
CreateSocket();

while(1)
{
     TASK1(Task2ms_Raster);
     TASK2(Task10ms_Raster);
     TASK3(Task100ms_Raster);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike QNX the Linux kernel is open source software. Which means that you can modify and change it in whatever ways you desire. You grab the sources from http://kernel.org (preferrably you use Git to clone into a local repository), make your modifications, additions, etc. compile the think and boot your computer with it.

Note that Linux since version 2.6 also offers realtime scheduling, which might be sufficient.

#### Update code example

For the time raster task execution I suggest the following:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   500

#include <sched.h>  /* for sched_setsched */
#include <unistd.h> /* for usleep */
#include <time.h>   /* for clock_gettime */
#include <string.h> /* for memset */

#define MS_to_US(x) ((x)*1000)

useconds_t delta_t_us(struct timespec const *a, struct timespec const *b)
{
    time_t const delta_sec  = b->tv_sec  - a->tv_sec;
    long   const delta_nsec = b->tv_nsec - a->tv_nsec;

    /* this might actually overflow for "long" time intervalls"
     * should be safe for a delta_t < 2ms though */
    return delta_sec * 1000000 + delta_nsec / 1000;
}

void rastertask()
{
    struct sched_param sparm;
    memset(&sparm, 0, sizeof(sparm));
    sparm.sched_priority = 10; /* 0 = lowest, 99 = highest */

    sched_setscheduler(
        0 /* pid, 0 ==> this process */,
        SCHED_RR /* policy */,
        &sparm);

    unsigned int n_loop;
    for(n_loop=0;;n_loop++) {
        struct timespec ts_start, ts_end;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_start);

        TASK1(); /* gets called every 2ms */
        if( (n_loop % 5) == 0) {
            TASK2(); /* get called every 5 * 2ms = 10ms */
        }
        if( (n_loop % 50) == 0) {
            TASK2(); /* get called every 50 * 2ms = 100ms */
        }

        if( (n_loop % 250) == 0 ) {
            /* reset loop counter when smallest common
             * multiple of timing grid has been reached */
            n_loop = 0;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_end);
        useconds_t const tasks_execution_time = delta_t_us(&ts_start, &ts_end);

        if( tasks_execution_time >= MS_to_US(2) ) {
            /* report an error that tasks took longer than 2ms to execute */
        }

        /* wait for 2ms - task_execution_time so that tasks get called in
         * a close 2ms timing grid */
        usleep( MS_to_US(2) - tasks_execution_time );
    }
}
```

Please note that the process requires either CAP_SYS_NICE privileges (prior to Linux 2.6.12) or sufficient RLIMIT_RTPRIO resource limits to be able to set its priority.

Comment: If I want to modify the interrupt then what should i do ?

Comment: @user3458454: You don't modify "the" interrupt. Why? Because in a typical system there are hundred of different interrupt sources. Anyway, what you do is, you write a interrupt handler and register it with the kernel to be called upon interrupt requests of the interrupt source you're interested in. Now the question remains? Why do you want to operate in kernel space? Normally you do that only when you're implementing a device driver or a kernel subsystem –– Seriously, if you have to ask questions like you did, then you should not mess around in the kernel. **What is it you want to do anyway?**

Comment: Server is the embedded pc target (containing a real time linux) and client is sending a data via the ethernet interface. When the server receives the data on the ethernet layer the interrupt occurs in the kernel. so I want to write a interrupt handler to handle interrupt from the client and register it with kernel: My question - where to write a interrupt handler and how to register it with kernel ??

Comment: to write code using RTLinux you need to code in kernel space and with kernel modules. With QNX, you can't write kernel modules (the kernel is not open) and you have real-time in user-space.

Comment: @user3458454: Ethernet? So you want to write an interrupt handler for the network card? And then what? Do you want to do the whole network processing yourself? You do realize that networking is nasty business and not for the faint of heart. When it comes to Ethernet an interrupt handler has to do a lot of things (reading the Ethernet frame from the NIC, test checksums, etc.) handing it over to the networking stack, that reassembles the packets, does security checks, etc. All this is already implemented in Linux for you to use. You don't implement **that** yourself.

Comment: @user3458454: I think you completely misunderstood what RTLinux means. In RTLinux you put those parts into kernel modules that have hard timing requirements. That are things like sensor to motor control loops. Networking never has hard realtime requirements (each hop on the way may unkown latencies). So you want to read data from an ethernet interface? Have a program running in user space as a regular process using the socket API (`socket(…); bind(…); listen(…); accept(…)`). **Kernel modules in RTLinux are meant for small, simple stuff, like PID controllers or actuator control or such**.

Comment: I already created a ethernet interface for receiving the data from the client via the socket. I am calculating the latency here (what you said is right).  Scenario : Client is sending a data and the server is receving the data from client via ethernet layer (udp). When the server receives a data from the client on the ip layer (kernel). It interrupts the kernel and kernel as to execute the data by the client, so I want to create a interrupt service function to catch the interrupt from the network service card. how and where to add the interrupt handler (ISR) in kernel module ?

Comment: @user3458454: You don't. Registering an interrupt handler for the network card means, that you've to do all the nasty network stuff. What you want to do is waking up the client in response to new data arriving. Use the [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) API for lowest latency. Once you've set up and called `epoll_wait` your process will sleep until data arrives. –– from your approach to the problem I take it, that you're used to microcontroller programming, where directly dealing with interrupts on the application level is common practice. But with (RT)Linux you don't do this.

Comment: I am handling interrupts to trigger the embedded pc target (conatining rt linux). My supervisor said that to write the code in kernel mode and compile with it. Is that possible ?? my understanding is wrong ?? if it is correct then where to write the interrupt hanler function in kernel mode and how to compile with the existing kernel code ??

Comment: @user3458454: Yes it's certainly possible, but not necessarily wise to do it. It really depends on what the code is doing. Everything network and I/O related should be done in user space, because it's just not very smart trying to do it in kernel mode (notable exception: network file systems, but only because file systems traditionally live in the kernel). Normally you keep the amount of code executing in kernel mode to a minimum and move as much as possible to user space.

Comment: @user3458454: Say you're developing a robot control system: You'd put the whole motor control and sensor readout into the kernel to get hard realtime. But all the communications with other systems and the higher level logic do not need can by principle can not act with realtime behavior so you put them into user space. The user space part interacts with the kernel mode part through device node I/O and ioctl, syscall, or sysfs.

Comment: In real time linux : it is not possible to handle the interrupt in user space (because it is a open source and there is no real time capability in user space), so it is not able to trigger the embedded pc target (kernel) and can't gain attention to process the recieved data. is that right ?? is there any other possibility to handle this ??

Comment: @user3458454: Open Source has nothing to do with it. Interrupts can not be handled in user space, because the only mode in which a interrupt can run is kernel mode. But that's not a problem. You're interested in doing network I/O. Network I/O is not realtime, because networks have undefined latencies. You can do networking code in user space just fine and data arriving from network can trigger code in user space by using epoll. **In few words: You do not need to write an interrupt handler for what you want to do.**

Comment: Server is embedded pc target with rt linux. When server receives a data from the client then the Interrupt handler is needed - isnt it ??

Comment: @user3458454: Interrupt handler is not needed. Linux kernel already does interrupt handling for you. Linux kernel will wake up program waiting for network data when network data arrives.

Comment: what you said is right!!! whenever the data arrived on the ethernet layer the network service card will interrupt saying that some data as arrived (As far as i know, It is not on the kernel level) but I need a Interrupt service routine to handle this and to enable the kernel to stop what it is currently doing and start processing the newly arrived data. what you say for this ?? is it wrong ??

Comment: @user3458454: Linux already contains all the interrupt handling for network data. You don't have to do anything regarding this. Data arrives, Linux will process it (in the kernel) and pass it to the process waiting for the data. **You do not write interrupt handlers for network devices yourself.** You don't have to write an interrupt handler, because all the interrupt handlers needed are already provided by Linux. Just have your program read or epoll on the opened socket. Trust me. It will just work that way.

Comment: I am adding my code then tell me where should i add the epoll or read??

Comment: how the embedded pc target with rt linux (this is my server) will come to know ?? please start the new conversation. I am new in stackoverflow, so I cant start a new conversation.

Comment: @user3458454: If the socket has been opened in blocking mode `recvfrom` will wait (=block) until data has arrived or a timeout happened. If you disable timeout `recvfrom` will not resume program until data has arrived. TASK1, TASK2, TASK3 seem to need periodic execution with hard timing requirements; put TASK1, TASK2 and TASK3 into separate thread that is put into hard realtime scheduling mode using [sched_setscheduler](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) to SCHED_RR.

Comment: @user3458454: You select nonblocking mode by calling recvfrom with the MSG_DONTWAIT flag (4th parameter of recvfrom). Yes, you should create a new thread from main, put it into SCHED_RR mode and use usleep to implement a 2ms wakeup raster. Count the number of wakeups to trigger 10ms and 100ms tasks.

Comment: could you please give me a example for SCHED_RR mode and usleep to implement a 2ms wakeup raster ??

Comment: million thanks for the example and if i make struct sched_param sparm; saprm.priority =sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR);  is it okay ??

Comment: @user3458454: Yes, you can do that. But in practice you should use the lowest priority you can get by with the system still working.

Comment: why is it necessary to calculate starttime and stoptime ?? how task1 gets called for 2ms ?

Comment: why i need starttime, stoptime and useconds_t const tasks_execution_time = delta_t_us(&ts_start, &ts_end); ??  if you dont mind then can i have your email id ??

Comment: usleep will make the program pause for the number of microseconds passed in as parameter. Since executing code required time, but we want to start tasks exactly on the 2ms timing grid we have to determine how long the tasks require to execute and subtract that amount of time from the delay inserted between executions. Thus we delay the loop in a way, that each loop iteration takes almost exactly 2ms. Since task1 is called with every loop iteration, task1 is called every 2ms.

Comment: I am getting error in tv_nsec and tv_sec is not a structure or union in     time_t const delta_sec  = b.tv_sec  - a.tv_sec;
    long   const delta_nsec = b.tv_nsec - a.tv_nsec;                     // to get a milli second - I modified as  return delta_sec * 1000 + delta_nsec / 1000000;

Comment: @user3458454: Ah, yes, a feature test macro was missing. See the `#define` at my code example added.

Comment: I am getting error in tv_nsec and tv_sec is not a structure or union in     time_t const delta_sec  = b.tv_sec  - a.tv_sec;
    long   const delta_nsec = b.tv_nsec - a.tv_nsec;                     // to get a milli second - I modified as  return delta_sec * 1000 + delta_nsec / 1000000;   I want to call the task for 2milli seconds, 10milli seconds . is this right ?   I added #define then also error

Comment: what could be the library for qnx ??

Comment: @user3458454: Sorry I had a few small syntax errors in that. I fixed them. When using the code you also will have to link with the `librt' library (`-lrt` compiler linker option). I can't tell you about QNX, I never developed software for it (yet).

Comment: I think to return the milli second then I should do  return delta_sec * 1000 + delta_nsec / 1000000;  what you say ??

Comment: @user3458454: Yes that would return milliseconds. But we do want microseconds there, ms are not precise enough. Also usleep takes microseconds not milliseconds.

Comment: but the tasks are getiing called for every 2milli seconds, 10milli seconds and so on ?? is it ?? why should not use CLOCK_REALTIME instead of clock monotonic ??

Comment: @user3458454: 1millisecond = 1000microseconds – usleep expects microseconds, hence we use that. The name of CLOCK_REALTIME is deceiving. A better name for it would be CLOCK_WALLTIME. The time reported by CLOCK_REALTIME is not monotonic and may jump. If you go from daylight saving time to regular time it will even jump backwards. For timing tasks you want to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

Comment: thank you very much and my last question is : is the task1 is getting called for 2milli second ?? what is MS, US and ms in your code ??

Comment: @user3458454: The task is called every 2ms. It will run completely through one iteration without being preempted. MS_to_US is a macro to convert milliseconds (ms) to microseconds (often abbreviates us). Macros are normally written in capital letters so ms → MS, us → US. 1ms = 1000us. Using that macro makes it clear that this is just a unit conversion. Writing `usleep( t * 1000 )` reeks of magic numbers, writing `usleep( MS_to_US(t) )` makes it clear that `t` is in units of ms, and gets converted to us for usleep.

Comment: thank you very very much!!! if I want some tasks to keep on running in the back ground then what should i do ?? my scenario : client will be triggering the tasks in the server, so I want the 2ms task, 10ms second and 100ms should be keep on running in the background, so that client can trigger.

Comment: shall i use pthread_create ?? could you please answer this also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708390/kernel-interrupt-debugging-for-rt-linux-or-qnx

Comment: hey hi!!! why the above code stops after executing after certain time ?? (example : if the TASK's are printing hi, hi1, hi2 - it will print till certain time and after that it will stop printing). could you please tell me why ?

Comment: @user3458454: Difficult to remote debug this over StackOverflow. I suggest you use a debugger to look into the innards of the process and if all variables have sensible values.